# restricting network access to localhost from a selinux policy

Tags: selinux

I have 2 applications that communicate with each other through TCP sockets and act as a client-server. I want to put them in 2 different SELinux sandboxes and allow network access only to localhost. I have labeled the localhost node with a custom type using semanage.

I have 2 issues:

1) the server listens on 0.0.0.0. The context type of the target object is node_t. Is there a way to allow the server to bind to 0.0.0.0 but only receive connections from localhost?

2) the client can connect to any node even if the are no rules that allow generic node_t access.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Network filtering support was removed from SELinux (http://lists.openwall.net/netdev/2009/03/27/144) and you need to use iptables and secmark to properly label traffic.